# Get anonymous space permissions even if anonymous is deactivated

Tags: confluence, atlassian-plugin-sdk

I try to get the space permissions of the anonymous users. I found the method [hasPermission](https://docs.atlassian.com/atlassian-confluence/6.2.1/com/atlassian/confluence/security/SpacePermissionManager.html#hasPermission-java.lang.String-com.atlassian.confluence.spaces.Space-com.atlassian.user.User-) from the SpacePermissionManager, which states that you can use null for the user if you want to get the anonymous rights. This works fine, except the anonymous access is deactivated in the global permissions. Then it always return false. Is there a way to get the anonymous space permissions even if the global access is deactived?

Background: There are still permissions settings for the anonymous in every space, even with the global deactivated. The thing is that authenticated users inherit these rights, so there is a reason to get this.